# Spring Autowired Exception when a remote ejb is down

Tags: java, spring, ejb, autowired, lazy-initialization

Hi, 
I have a simple question that I am not able to solve.

I'm using Spring 3 to lookup Remote ejbs and I added lazy-init=true into bean definition because my application must starting 
also if some ejb is down. 
Unfortunately my controller when autowiring of an ejb that is down, I get "Injection of autowired dependencies failed".

Someone can help me! Is @Autowired not lazy? It's possible, using spring, start my web application also if some remote ejb is not started?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700338/spring-autowired-lazy)?

Comment: I have resolved with [this][1], using jee:remote-slsb instead of bean declaration.


  [1]: http://swat.nexse.com/tag/ejb/