# Circular reference in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to update Spring Boot application from 2.4 to 2.6.4 but I am getting following error:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
┌─────┐
|  webSecurityConfig
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.
└─────┘
```

Following is WebSecurityConfig code:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.jay.liqui.jwt.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import com.jay.liqui.jwt.JwtTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Configuration
//@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;


    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new  BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //Cross-origin-resource-sharing: localhost:8080, localhost:4200(allow for it.)
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //These are public paths
                .antMatchers("/resources/**",  "/error", "/api/user/**").permitAll()
                //These can be reachable for just have admin role.
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                //All remaining paths should need authentication.
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                //logout will log the user out by invalidated session.
                .logout().permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/logout", "POST"))
                .and()
                //login form and path
                .formLogin().loginPage("/api/user/login").and()
                //enable basic authentication
                .httpBasic().and()
                //We will handle it later.
                //Cross side request forgery
                .csrf().disable();

        //jwt filter
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),jwtTokenProvider));
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
        authBuilder.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from usr01 where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from usr01 where username=?")
        ;


    }

    //Cross origin resource sharing.
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the console log of the application on startup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Autowired @Lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700338/spring-autowired-lazy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this error is
Spring Boot 2.4 disable spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding by default and Spring Boot 2.6.4 enable

There are 2 solutions to fix it

Solution 1: You set allow-bean-definition-overriding is true in application.properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Solution 2: You should move Bean WebMvcConfigurer to another class

Example:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    LogInterceptor logInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(logInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }

}

@Component
public class LogInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    LoggingService loggingService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        if (DispatcherType.REQUEST.name().equals(request.getDispatcherType().name()) && request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.name())) {
            loggingService.logRequest(request, null);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: where is 'logInterceptor' coming from?

Comment: it is file handle interceptor of mine. I updated my answer